# Sample from 2 category with different probabilities without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

I have three problems about sampling without replacement, where the next is generalization of the other.

We are picking $k$ balls without replacement from an ur with $n_1$ white balls and $n_2$ black balls (so that the total amount of balls are $n = n_1 + n_2$ and $k < n$). Each white ball is weighted with a probability $p_1$ to be picked, and each black ball is weighted with a probability $p_2 = 1-p_1$ to be picked.

**1)** Assume that there is only $n_1 =1$ white ball and the rest are black, that is, $n_2 = n-1 > 0$. When picking $k$ balls (without replacement), what is the probability that atleast one of these are the white one?

**2) (Generalization of 1)** Assume that there are $n_1 \geq  1$ white balls and the rest are black, that is, $n_2 = n-n_1 > 0$. When picking $k$ balls (without replacement), what is the probability that atleast one of these are the white one?

**3) (Generalization of 2)** Assume that there are $n_1$ white balls, but there might be zero white balls ($n_1$ might equal $0$) and the rest are black ($n_2 = n-n_1 > 0$). When picking $k$ balls (without replacement), what is the probability that atleast one of these are the white one? Assume that the probability of white balls being in the urn is $p_0$.

I guess **1)** can be calculated using complements and **3)** be calculated with conditional probabilties, assuming that you know **2)**, but I'm not sure.

I appreciate all help I can get.

**EDIT:** My suggested solutions:

**EDIT2**: Clarified my question and fixed my suggested solution:

**1)** and **2)**

\begin{align*}
P(\text{atleast one white}) &= 1 - P(\text{no white}) \\ 
&= \frac{n_2p_2}{n}\cdot\frac{(n_2-1)p_2}{n-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{(n_2-k+1)p_2}{n-k+1} \\
&= 1 - \prod^k_{i=1}\frac{(n_2-i+1)p_2}{n-i+1}
\end{align*}

**3)**
\begin{align*}
P(\text{atleast one white}) 
&= 1 - P(\text{no white}) \\ 
&= 1 - \left(P(n_1>0)P(\text{no white}| n_1>0)+P(n_1=0)P(\text{no white}| n_1=0)\right)\\
&= 1 - \left(p_0\cdot\left(\prod^k_{i=1}\frac{(n_2-i+1)p_2}{n-i+1}\right) + (1-p_0)\cdot1\right)\\
&= p_0 - p_0\cdot\left(\prod^k_{i=1}\frac{(n_2-i+1)p_2}{n-i+1}\right)
\end{align*}

Could anyone confirm that this is correct?

Comment: I would use your strategies for 1) and 2) too. Also for 3) the conditional probabilities are fine since you are conditioning on two mutual disjoints event.

Comment: @Enrico I came up with a suggested solution. Could u confirm if it is correct?

Comment: I understood badly, sorry. Do you mean that when we know that $n_1=1$ we only extract 1 ball or that when there will be only 1 white ball, after some sampling, we will extract 1 more ball and stop?

Comment: @Enrico when $n_1 = 1$, there is only 1 white ball but we still extract $k$ balls in total.

Comment: @Enrico Each white ball is weighted with probability p1
 of being picked and each black ball is weighted with probability p2=1−p1
 of being picked. You dont consider that

Comment: @Enrico Probability of picking a white in first trail is $p_1n_1/n$. In second trail it is $p_1n_1/n$ if a black was picked in first trail, and its $p_1(n_1-1)/n$ if a white was being picked. Same goes for black (but then $p_2$), and this proceeds for the $k$ trails. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are fixed yes.

Comment: If so I think your calculations are right, even if I do not understand why it could be useful to scale the basic probabilities with the $p_i, i=1,2$.

Comment: @Enrico It's a problem that occured at my job and I needed to know if my solution was correct. Thanks for you inputs!